# Error compiling C program with DevCpp when using inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I am using DevCpp to compile the following code but a problem occurs:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char s;

    __asm(
    "mov %ah, 1"
    "int 21h"
    "mov %ah,2"
    "mov %dl,%al"
    "int 21h"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

The error produced by the DevCpp compiler is:

> Error: junk `int 21hmov %ah' after expression Error: too many memory
>   references for`mov'

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: your assembler is seeing it all as one string... what assembler is this you're using?

Comment: append an `\n\t` at every line of assembly code

Comment: Did you read the faq on this [devcpp](http://www.bloodshed.net/faq.html#16)

Comment: as mentioned you'd at least need `\n` on the end of each string, `\n\t` looks prettier in generated output since it indents. But even if you compile this `int 21h` will not work properly if you generate a Windows executable. Dev-CPP is a 32-bit compiler, and doesn't target DOS. GCC will likely complain about the use of the `h` suffix for hex, and you'd have to be compiling with `-masm=intel` to use intel styntax. But `int 21h` will crash your Windows app when it encounters that instruction.

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ demonstrates doing one statement in each `__asm`.

```
__asm("mov %ah, 1") ;
__asm("int 21h"   ) ;
__asm("ONE AND ONLY ONE INSTRUCTION") ;
```

You *should* be able to separate lines with a `\n`, but I don't see that documented.

```
__asm("mov %ah, 1\n"
      "int 21h   \n"
      "MULTIPLE INSTRUCTIONS WITH \n") ;
```

Comment: It is guaranteed. In GCC the use of `__asm` will force the lines to be emitted into assembly code which will be processed by GNU assembler (`as`) . Since new lines can separate instructions in GNU assembler it is completely valid to separate instruction in `__asm` with `\n` as well. `\n\t` is usually what you see since it pretties the assembler code generated if you tell `as` or `gcc` to emit the intermediate assembly code.

Comment: Have commented to the OP above that the faq states explicitly, `__asm` for each line of assembly...

Comment: If I remember correctly, using `;` to separate assembly instructions in the same `__asm` block in GCC worked just fine for me...